# How to get list type elements using reflection in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a class : Transaction.cs

```
public class Transaction
{
    public int Transaction_id  { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
}
```

I want too use reflection to get the values that are in the collection of transactions ie :

```
var db = new List<Transaction>();
var temp = new Transaction { Transaction_id = 123, Item = "AKP", Description = "Startup" };
var info = temp.GetType().GetProperties();
db.Add(new Transaction { Transaction_id = 45, Item = "RW", Description = "Starting" });
var type = typeof(Transaction);
var prop = type.GetProperty("Item");
var value = prop.GetValue(temp);
```

added this code for loop on properties:

```
foreach (var testing in db.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var sample = testing.GetValue(db);
    Console.WriteLine(sample);
}
```

i get a value of 4 displayed in command line.

which would give me the value of AKP on screen. Now how does it work when i have a list of transactions?

Thanks

Comment: you would have to do a foreach if I am understanding your question correctly to iterate thru the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generic lists are type-safe so you don't need to use reflection.

To iterate over the list, use `foreach`.

```
var db = new List<Transaction>
{
    new Transaction { Transaction_id = 123, Item = "AKP", Description = "Startup" }, 
    new Transaction { Transaction_id = 45, Item = "RW", Description = "Starting" }
}
foreach (var transaction in db)
{
    Console.WriteLine(transaction.Item);
}
```

Output:

```
AKP
RW
```

If you truly need to use Reflection, and this sort of thing is common in your code base, I'd take the time to write an extension method like this one:

```
static T GetPropertyByName<T>(this object input, string name) 
{
    return (T)input
        .GetType()
        .GetProperty(name, BindingFlags.Instance)
        .GetValue(input);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
foreach (var transaction in db)
{
    Console.WriteLine(transaction.GetPropertyByName<string>("Item"));
}
```

Or if you don't know the names of the properties ahead of time:

```
foreach (var row in db)
{
    foreach (var p in row.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.GetValue(row));
    }
}
```

Comment: i am attempting to use reflection to take in object of any type and get the values at run time so reflection is necessary here

Comment: no you can do this with any class / object I have deleted an example showing how you could do this.. you could do this using a Generic Class of where T : Class

Answer (score 0):

For example if I want to set all of the properties to string.Empty in my class I would do something like this, you could apply the same logic in the foreach loop to get your property types etc..

```
public static void ConvertNullToStringEmpty<T>(this T clsObject) where T : class
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = clsObject.GetType().GetProperties();//typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (var info in properties)
    {
        // if a string and null, set to String.Empty
        if (info.PropertyType == typeof(string) && info.GetValue(clsObject, null) == null)
        {
            info.SetValue(clsObject, String.Empty, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you got this list:

```
var transactionList = new List<Transaction>
{
   new Transaction { Transaction_id = 123, Item = "AKP", Description = "Startup" },
   new Transaction { Transaction_id = 45, Item = "RW", Description = "Starting" }
};
```

You can navigate property names of the each item in the collection by reading a single item's properties while iterating the list:

```
foreach (var item in transactionList)
{
     foreach (var property in item.GetType().GetProperties())
     {
         Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", property.Name, property.GetValue(item, null));
     }                
}

Console.ReadLine();
```